# Oracle SQL: Use IN operator with inline array

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Is it possible to define an inline array to use with the `IN` operator in Oracle SQL 12c? Pseudo code:

```
SELECT *
FROM T_AUDIO_PLAYERS
WHERE NAME IN {'foo', 'bar'};
```

Background: I have a Java tool, that's reading in valid .SQL files and replaces SQL-Variables like `:NAME` before execution.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you mean by user defined array? You mean dynamic IN list? Also, `{}` is invalid syntax, you need to use `()`.

Comment: I just meant inline, without the need to declare the array elsewhere.

Comment: You can't declare the IN list to use it dynamically in SQL. You need to simply provide the static values at run time, `WHERE NAME IN ('foo', 'bar')`.

Comment: Oracle has no array data type for SQL (it has arrays in PL/SQL, but that is something different)

Comment: Were you required to get dynamic values for IN clause?

Comment: In short: Kind of. Long version: I have a static, valid .sql file, containig e.g. `:VALS` on one hand and a Java backend on the other hand. The Java backend loads these .sql files and dynamically replaces `:VALS` with values from the Java world (in this case `{'foo', 'bar'}`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. However, if you change your {-brackets to (-brackets, this should already work:

```
SELECT *
FROM T_AUDIO_PLAYERS
WHERE NAME IN ('foo', 'bar');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LISTAGG` function like

```
SELECT *
FROM T_AUDIO_PLAYERS
WHERE NAME IN (select LISTAGG() ...);
```

More detail [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030)